# attaching chatter feed to a record

Tags: chatter, chatter-feed-tracking

Is there a way of attaching a Chatter post to the feed of a record, e.g., a case, after it has been created already with a different parent. Here is an illustration:
If a work buddy has raised a case and had it resolved only to find out that they need to ask another question about the same issue, is it possible for the post to be attached to the feed of the case it relates to. I know that technically the user would normally have to go to the record and then post, but is it possible for them to post and then attach to the record?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDITED response: Upon clarification in the comments, the answer to your question is no, it is not possible to change the parent record associated with a Chatter FeedItem. FeedItem is not an updatable sObject, they can only be created and deleted.

Comment: thanks but your answer does not address the question.

Comment: Re-reading your question again, it seems like you may be asking if you can post somewhere in Chatter and then later associate that post with a record, is that what you're asking? About re-parenting chatter feed items?

Comment: now you have it.

Comment: Let me edit my response then to the correct answer, which is no, this is not possible.

Comment: Now that we know it's not possible, I've addded it as an idea to Success.Salesforce.com, if any one wants to vote on it here is the link: https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000l6MnAAI